# How do I know all stored procedures in SQL Server that have no dependencies so I can safely drop them?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have lots of stored procedures that have no dependencies and I believe is no longer being used, but are not yet dropped.

How do I find these procedures in SQL Server so I can drop them?

Answer (score 1):

To view the dependencies of a procedure in Object Explorer

1. In Object Explorer, connect to an instance of Database Engine and then expand that instance.
2. Expand Databases, expand the database in which the procedure belongs, and then expand Programmability.
3. Expand Stored Procedures, right-click the procedure and then click View Dependencies.
4. View the list of objects that depend on the procedure.
5. View the list of objects on which the procedure depends.
6. Click OK.

or you can directly follow the steps given in the link for Transact-SQL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms345404.aspx